# ZipFile creating zip with all the folders in zip

Tags: python-3.x, zip

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html), I picked follwing snippet to zip a single file (For a flask project).

I have to create a zip file in temploc here:
`/home/workspace/project/temploc/zipfile.zip`

And here is my file to be zipped:
`/home/workspace/project/temploc/file_to_be_zipped.csv`

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
def zip_file(self, output, file_to_zip):
    try:
      with ZipFile(output, 'w') as myzip:
        myzip.write(file_to_zip)
    except:
        return None
    return output
```

This code creating a zip file in `temploc` but with full directory structure of zip file path.

```
  def prepare_zip(self):
      cache_dir = app.config["CACHE_DIR"] #-- /home/workspace/project/temploc
      zip_file_path = os.path.join(cache_dir, "zipfile.zip")
      input_file = '/home/workspace/project/temploc/file_to_be_zipped.csv'
      self.zip_file(zip_file_path, input_file)
```

But above code is creating a zip file with given path directory structure:

```
zipfile.zip    
├──home 
│   ├── workspace
│   │   └── project
│   │       └──temploc 
│   │           └── file_to_be_zipped.csv
```

BUt I want only this structure:

```
zipfile.zip    
   └── file_to_be_zipped.csv
```

I'm not getting what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shuld use [second argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) of `ZipFile.write` to set proper name of file in archive:

```
import os.path

...

myzip.write(file_to_zip, os.path.basename(file_to_zip))
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Had forgot to accept the answer.Thanks :)